# Varnish-modules make check fails completely

Tags: varnish

I have a new server, ubuntu 20.04.02.lts, fully patched.  I've installed varnish 6.6.0 and it starts correctly.  I've downloaded the varnish-modules file from github, 0.18.0.tar.gz, and unzipped it (varnish-modules-0.18.0).

I've installed all the prerequisites identified here:

Compiling, testing and installing relies on the autotools suite and requires:

the usual autotools dependencies (make, automake, libtool)
the Varnish development files (varnish-dev or varnish-devel)
rst2man (python-sphinx) (actually for 20.04 it was sphinx-common)

I follow these steps:

./bootstrap

./configure   # run "configure -h" first to list options

make

make check    # optional (tests).

all the tests (55 total) fail. the make command appears to be fine.

i discovered this error in the test-suite.log file - /root/tmp/varnish-modules-0.18.0/src/.libs/libvmod_var.so: cannot open shared object file: Permission denied

I'm running as root.  The file exists and has these permissions:

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 75256 Apr  7 05:09 /root/tmp/varnish-modules-0.18.0/src/.libs/libvmod_var.so

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, there was some security on the /root partition that was preventing the make check command from reading any file in the root/tmp/varnish-modules-0.18.0/src/.libs folder.

I moved the varnish-modules folder to my home folder and could successfully run the make check command.